# Constraint layout design for scroll view for recycler view

Tags: android

```
I need scroll view effect for the view inside scroll views and in the below code scroll view does not have any effect.I have connected card view to guide line and scroll view to guide line don't know because of fixed guild line scroll view is not working can any one help me in refactoring the xml with scroll view working?.
```

I m new to constraint layout design so i m not interested in nested constraint layout design. So i have taken only one ConstraintLayout as parent need to improve with this.
Any help is appreciated.

below is my xml code :

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/cardView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                app:cardElevation="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0">

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.38030097" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewAccType"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cardView"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/cardView"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_icons_casa" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView57"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:text=""
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/light_grey"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewAccType"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewAccType"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageViewAccType" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView20"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView68"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/bottom_bar" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView68"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text=""
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/light_grey"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cardView"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView18" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView69"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:text="checking.."
                android:textColor="@color/light_grey"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView62"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView18" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView58"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cardView"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView57" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView59"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:text="Currency"
                android:textColor="@color/light_grey"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView58"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView57" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView60"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/light_grey"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cardView"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView58" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView61"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView60"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView59" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView15"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/cardView"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cardView"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView61"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/bottom_bar" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView18"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cardView"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView62"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/bottom_bar" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView62"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/light_grey"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cardView"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView15" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView67"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:text="checking.."
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/cardView"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView62"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView15" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView70"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/cardView"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView20" />

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_bar"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3">

            </ScrollView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView71"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="RECENT BDA PAY TRANSACTIONS"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/scroll_view"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView72"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="View All"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/scroll_view"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView71"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="152dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline14"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/scroll_view"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/scroll_view"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView71" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView14"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="152dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text=""
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/light_grey"
                android:textSize="@dimen/size_16"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView74"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.51"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/scroll_view"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView72"/>

            <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.6497948" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView74"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="RECENT BDA PAY REQUESTS"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/scroll_view"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline14" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView94"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="View All"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/scroll_view"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView74"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline14" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="152dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_bar"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/scroll_view"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/scroll_view"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView74" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView15"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="152dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text=""
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/light_grey"
                android:textSize="@dimen/size_16"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/scroll_view"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.51"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/scroll_view"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView74" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
                layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_layout_new"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I m new to constraint layout design so i m not interested in nested constraint layout design. So i have taken only one ConstraintLayout as parent need to improve with this.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: any help is appreciated!

Comment: use nested scrollView

Comment: nested scrollview also not working

Comment: my doudt is because of horizontal guide line scrollview is not working....

Comment: scrollView should contain only one childView

Comment: should i need to add one more constraint layout inside scroll view?

Comment: try below example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ScrollView should contain only one childView

example:

```
<ScrollView>

<ConstarinLayout>
.
.
.
.
</ConstraintLayout>

</Scrollview>
```

Then only it works..